# Why does numpy.where behave differently for "== None" and "is None" when trying to find None elements in array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to find all None elements in an array using np.where. This is my code:

```
a = np.array([None, 1, 2, None, 3])
print(np.where(a is None)[0])
print(np.where(a == None)[0])
```

Oddly, using "a is None" returns an empty array, while using "a==None" returns the correct result. I wonder why this is happening? Thanks!

Update: If a is a python list, then both will behave the same and return []. The difference will only happen when a is cast to an ndarray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: Both lines should be executed as `print(np.where(False)[0])`.

Comment: I've edited the code. Turns out casting a to an ndarry will result in the behavior I described, while keeping it as a list will cause both lines to return [].

Comment: Operator "is" can't be overloaded and always checks identity while "==" can be (and is here) overloaded to produce a result which can be further processed by "np.where".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a is None` checks whether `a` itself is `None`, and **does NOT check the elements of** `a` **against** `None`. In other words, `a` is `None` if `a` itself is `None`. So, `a is None` returns `False` here since `a` is not empty. Now, `np.where(a is None)` is equivalent to `np.where(False)` which is empty and hence its first element is empty as well, returning `[]`.

On the other hand `a == None` checks elements of `a` against `None` and will return `array([ True, False, False,  True, False])` which results in the output you see.

In short:

```
a is None
#False

a == None
#array([ True, False, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. Combining you answer with Michael Butscher's comment above, is my following understanding correct? If a is a Python list, then both "is None" and "== None" will check if a itself is None. If a is an ndarray, then for '==', because it is overloaded for ndarray, it can achieve element-wise comparison, while "is None" cannot be overloaded, so it won't have the same effect.

Comment: @edwardliang2019 For a list `==` is also overloaded but the implementation only returns True if the object to compare with is also a list of same length and contains items in same order which are equal to the respective items of a. It returns False otherwise.